# Sliding Tabs like the new Google Play Store 5.0

Tags: android, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

How can I implement a Sliding Tabs like in the new Google Play Store 5.0?

[click for the image](http://cdn.ndtv.com/tech/images/google_play_store_50_new_homescreen_leak_android_police.jpg)

I have seen so much examples, but all using a "addTab" that is deprecated or not run on android 2.x.
I need a example about this implementation.
My Idea is that in my APP the tabs will be created in according with the information that come of my Web Service. So my APP can have 3 tabs or 40 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an barebones example in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip

Also, here is the [PagerTitleStrip documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html).

Comment: I can't use this, because in the code have a deprecated methods, like "getActionBar()".

Comment: Did you read the page in the link? It says "If you **don't want to include action bar tabs** and **prefer to provide scrollable tabs** for a shorter visual profile, you can use PagerTitleStrip with your swipe views."

Comment: Yes, but I need to include my tabs on actionBar, because in my layout I don't want a border between the ActionBar and tab.